# Random jump in recursive function

Tags: c#, recursion

I wrote a recursive function that walks trough a maze/tunnel with condition that you can't move trough the same tiles back (if there's no tiles left to move function returns). Everything seems to work but at the end after `return;` part the function is being called again for no reason. Aditionally, `int[,] beenThere` will be used further in the code so it needs to be returned as it is.

```
 static public void Movement(int x,int y, int[,] coords, ref int[,] beenThere)
    {
        string bin = Convert.ToString(coords[x, y], 2).PadLeft(4, '0');

        beenThere[x, y] = 1;

        if (bin[0] == '0') // Bottom tile open
        {
            if(beenThere[x,y+1] == 0)
            {
                y++;
                Movement(x, y, coords, ref beenThere);
            }
        }

        if (bin[1] == '0') // Right tile open
        {
            if (beenThere[x + 1, y] == 0)
            {
                x++;
                Movement(x, y, coords, ref beenThere);
            }
        }

        if (bin[2] == '0') // Top tile open
        {
            if (beenThere[x, y - 1] == 0)
            {
                y--;
                Movement(x, y, coords, ref beenThere);
            }
        }

        if (bin[3] == '0')   // Left tile open
        {
            if (beenThere[x - 1, y] == 0)
            { 
                x--;
                Movement(x, y, coords, ref beenThere);
            }
        }

        // No tiles open, return back;
        Console.WriteLine("End of the tunnel.");
        return; // HERE LINE 12 OF CODE SNIPPET (CALLING THE FUNCTION) IS BEING RUN
    }
```

I tried debugging going step by step and found out that when the end condition is met, after passing `return;` part, program jumps to `line 12` of the snippet (the same function is called once again even though it had to return). What's the cause and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just returning to the caller? Since this function is recursive, it could easily *seem* like it is repeating itself.

Comment: That's how `recursive` works.

Comment: Each recursion step will continue after a return to hit the return. Are you sure you need the return? Seems to make your code more complex for no reason.

Comment: `// No tiles open, return back;` --> no, this code is reached for *every single call to Movement()* because no code path causes the function to abort before reaching that point!

Comment: This is how function calls work.  A function A calls another function B.  Once B is done, control returns to A, and it continues where it left off.  This is normal and expected.

Comment: This would be better as a stack and iteration instead of recursion, as soon as you get too many tiles your app will die, Advantages are, you will have an easier break, and its easier to debug

Comment: Might want to ditch the `x++` and `y++`, etc., and just call `Movement()` with `x+1`, `y+1`, etc. You're modifying the "center" location between each potential movement, which is possibly not what you want.

Comment: @themiDdlest this was a shortened code snippet, I need to return additional information later. I thought that hitting return once returns from all recursive calls made before, thanks for helpful comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a recursive function, so the function calls itself, as you know. But the function calling itself *does not* cause that function to stop execution and "goto" the new one. So, like any other code, *after the function returns, the code continues executing*. Like any other code:

```
public void DoStuff() {
  Console.WriteLine("Stuff");
}

public void Main() {
  Console.WriteLine("Before Stuff");
  DoStuff(); //control flow enters "DoStuff"
  //once DoStuff returns, code continues as normal - it's the same in recursion!
  Console.WriteLine("After Stuff");
}
```

Just replace `DoStuff()` with a recursive call and it's exactly the same.

In short: Add `return;`s after you call `Movement(...);` in each condition.

Comment: Well that makes sense, I'm quite new to recursion, thanks!